# The "path" argument must be of type string. Received type undefined (fs module nodejs)

Tags: javascript, node.js, macos

I am trying to check if a file exists using fs module in nodejs. Please refer to the following code:

```
var path = require('path');
let customXmlPath = (process.platform == 'darwin' ? path.join(__dirname, '../../MacOS/service/custom.xml') : path.join(__dirname, '../../service/custom.xml'));
if (isDevelopment) {
    customXmlPath = (process.platform == 'darwin' ? path.join(__dirname, '../../../build/bin/darwin/release/custom.xml') : path.join(__dirname, '../../../build/bin/msvc/release/custom.xml'));
}
console.log(customXmlPath);

const fs = require('fs');
let productDisplayName = "xxxxxx";
try {
    fs.accessSync(customXmlPath, fs.F_OK);
    let file = fs.readFileSync(customXmlPath, "utf8");
    var xmlr = require('../../../shared/electronUIshared/xmlreader.js').XMLReader;
    var datastore = xmlr.parse('config', file);
    if(datastore.getTotalCount() > 0)
    {
        productDisplayName = datastore.getRecordAt(0).get('productname');
    }
}
catch(err) {
    console.log("custom.xml not found or is corrupted. Using display name as xxxxxx")
}
```

In windows it works fine but in mac it throws an error in fs.acessSync: The "path" argument must be of type string. Received type undefined.

path.join returns correct path

Output:

```
/Users/nikhell/Documents/Codelathe/Workspace/cl-fc-client/build/bin/darwin/release/custom.xml
App threw an error during load
TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "path" argument must be of type string. Received type undefined
    at validateString (internal/validators.js:105:11)
    at Object.join (path.js:1037:7)
    at eval (webpack:///./src/background.ts?:70:21)
    at Module../src/background.ts (/Users/nikhell/Documents/Codelathe/Workspace/cl-fc-client/clouddrive2service/ui/dist_electron/index.js:6094:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (/Users/nikhell/Documents/Codelathe/Workspace/cl-fc-client/clouddrive2service/ui/dist_electron/index.js:20:30)
    at eval (webpack:///multi_./src/background.ts?:1:18)
    at Object.0 (/Users/nikhell/Documents/Codelathe/Workspace/cl-fc-client/clouddrive2service/ui/dist_electron/index.js:6201:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (/Users/nikhell/Documents/Codelathe/Workspace/cl-fc-client/clouddrive2service/ui/dist_electron/index.js:20:30)
    at /Users/nikhell/Documents/Codelathe/Workspace/cl-fc-client/clouddrive2service/ui/dist_electron/index.js:84:18
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/nikhell/Documents/Codelathe/Workspace/cl-fc-client/clouddrive2service/ui/dist_electron/index.js:87:10)
```

If i remove the file extension it does not throw the error but it is not able to find the file. Why is the file extension creating issues in mac?

Comment: So, `path.join` is throwing that error?

Comment: no, path.join works perfectly.. fs.accessSync throws error

Comment: Can you please add error logs ?

Comment: mode you passed as fs.F_OK but as per documentation it should be like fs.constants.R_OK

Comment: The stack trace seems to indicate that it is indeed `path.join`, no? I can't imagine `accessSync` is the issue, `customXmlPath` is never `undefined`.